# Apple "Remote Management" not working through ethernet

Tags: network, remote-desktop, ethernet, macos

In order to control my Mac mini, I use Apple's "Remote Management" feature. I have Remote Management enabled on the Mac mini, which allows me to control it from my MacBook Pro via the Screen Sharing App. I do this because I don't have a monitor for the mini.

Although this works well, I noticed that when I disconnect from WiFi on the mini, it stops the screen share, even though the mini is connected to my LAN using an Ethernet cable. In contrast, apps like TeamViewer and AnyDesk work just fine over Ethernet when WiFi is disabled.

Why doesn't Remote Management work over Ethernet, and how can I get it to work?

The reason I want it to work over Ethernet is because I want to make the Mac mini into a WiFi hotspot, which requires WiFi to be disabled. I do not want to use TeamView or AnyDesk for multiple reasons:

- Their quality seems to be quite bad. With Remote Desktop I can get almost-retina quality on my MacBook Pro, making it seem almost as though the mini is connected straight to my MacBook. However frame rate and smoothness suffers because of this.
- Remote management works at a lower level than the apps I mentioned, because they'll even let you log in after restarting your computer. I need that

Comment: A bit of guesswork - TeamViewer etc will themselves attempt to re-establish the connection to the remote [internet] server, & that will allow your 'direct' connection to be re-established. Screen Sharing is looking for the mini on a specific IP address, which you just removed. I'd try setting it up as two saved locations, one over Wifi, the other over ethernet. [I'm not particularly familiar with the simpler Screen Sharing, I use the full Apple Remote Desktop here.]

Comment: Thanks—I'm not really sure why I didn't realize this but I just needed to connect via the IP address of the ethernet network connection...